# WPF Datagrid's selected row has strange behaviour

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, row

I have WPF datagrid:

```
<DataGrid IsReadOnly="True" x:Name="PivotDataGridView" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="5,30,10,20" CanUserSortColumns="False" CellStyle="{StaticResource PivotCellStyle}" Grid.Column="1">
```

When I selected some row, it's looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/36d4X.png

Does anybody know how to fix it?

**EDIT:**

Here is used style:

```
<Style x:Key="PivotCellStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource DifferenceToTotalBrushConverter}}" />
</Style>
```

And here is converter:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        DataGridCell currentCell;

        try
        {
            var context = (value as DataGridCell).DataContext;
            var Prices = (context as PivotDataGridViewItem).Price;
            currentCell = value as DataGridCell;

            if (currentCell.Column.DisplayIndex > 3 && currentCell.Column.DisplayIndex % 2 == 0)
            {
                int index = GetIndexPrices(currentCell);

                if(index < Prices.Count)
                {
                    decimal currentPrice = Prices[index];
                    decimal totalPrice = Prices[0];

                    if (currentPrice != 0)
                    {
                        if (Math.Abs(currentPrice - totalPrice) < 0.20m && currentPrice != totalPrice)
                        {
                            return MainWindow.PivotCentPriceColor;
                        }
                        else if (currentPrice < totalPrice)
                        {
                            return MainWindow.PivotLowerPriceColor;
                        }
                        else if (currentPrice > totalPrice)
                        {
                            return MainWindow.PivotHigherPriceColor;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (InvalidCastException)
        {
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException)
        {
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {

        }

        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
```

Could be problem in not implementing ConvertBack?

Comment: I suppose it depends on the style of your DataGrid or maybe on the style of the Cell. You should post some additional info about it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that converter somehow modify highlighted row style. Modify backgroundcolor to white but keep font color white also. So text looks like hidden.

This helps me:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
     <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
           <Style.Resources>
                 <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="LightBlue" />
                 <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="LightBlue" />
                 <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
                 <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
           </Style.Resources>
      </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```